# Using IHttpHandler and Threadpool VS using IHttpAsyncHandler

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, ihttphandler

IHttpAsyncHandler means run the request asynchronously.

Using the thread pool also can run asynchronously.

So if I want to implement a function (like Comet,long poll), between using thread pool with IHttpHandler and using IHttpAsyncHandler, which is better?

EDIT:
@Jon Skeet:
Thank you for your patient reply. Let me make a conclusion. If I use delegate.BeginInvoke in the IHttpHandler,the 'Main Thread' of processing request still keeps spinning until the request end,no matter what happened with the pooled thread. If I use the IHttpAsyncHandler, the 'Main Thread' of processing request will call the BeginProcessRequest and after that,it will be released (to process other request). The BeginProcessRequest method will do something asynchronously. When the asynchronous action finished,the EndProcessRequest method will be called.(or we can say the 'Main Thread' will call the EndProcessRequest function to finished current request)

All above are what I think, is it right?

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "Using the thread pool also can run asynchronously."?

Comment: In IHttpHandlerm,I can use Action delegate, its method beginInvoke. This methond runs with a pooled thread.

Comment: Yes, but "running on a background thread" isn't the same as "running asynchronously". It means you'll still end up with one thread per request, which you don't want for long polling/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that with a *truly* asynchronous model, you don't need a thread per request at all. If you have a thread per request, whether or not it's on the thread pool, you'll be stuck handling a large number of connections (as you need to for things like long polling).

Suppose you have a hundred thousand clients, each long-polling - do you really want 100,000 threads? (Hint: I doubt that you've got enough memory...)

With genuine asynchrony, you can react to events by ending a request *without* having a dedicated thread per request. Note that with C# 5 and .NET 4.5, there are simpler ways than using `IHttpAsyncHandler`, too. It depends on what you're trying to achieve, but both WCF and MVC have async-oriented approaches where you can write an async method, using `await` expressions etc. If you then await something which doesn't in itself take a thread (e.g. a timer, or perhaps some IO completing) then you can manage a *huge* number of concurrent connections.

EDIT: To respond to your further questions: yes, if you use just `IHttpHandler`, the request *must* be completed when the `ProcessRequest` call completes. You can't just leave it "dangling"... whereas `IHttpAsyncHandler` allows the request to still be in progress until `EndProcessRequest` is called. Don't forget that this is a very old interface though - it's not terribly clearly documented, and I wouldn't suggest using it these days, when there are significantly better approaches to asynchrony, particularly using .NET 4.5 and C# 5. But the main point of being able to have a request in progress but without any specific thread being associated with it still holds.

Comment: You think using the IHttpAsyncHandler will not be stucked by handing the connection?

Comment: I think even using the IHttpAsyncHandler , the connection is still holden by someone thread.

Comment: @roast_soul: What makes you think that? The connection will still be maintained, but there won't be a thread just sitting around, as far as I'm aware. That would make it pointless and not really asynchronous.

Comment: :Thank you for your reply.